# JGit is causing duplicate classes error out of the box

Tags: java, android, gradle, jgit

Attempting to integrate JGit into an Android project and getting lots of duplicate classes ERRORs all coming from JGit transitive dependency:

Duplicate class detect shows among others:

```
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/closeable/SequentialCloseable.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/closeable/SimpleCloseable.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/functors/Int2IntFunction.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/functors/UnaryEquator.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/helper/LazyIterablesConcatenator$1.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/helper/LazyIterablesConcatenator.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/helper/LazyMatchingTypeIterable.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/helper/LazyMatchingTypeIterator.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
    - org/apache/sshd/common/util/io/CloseableEmptyInputStream.class is in [sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar, sshd-common-2.7.0.jar]
```

Both sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar AND sshd-common-2.7.0.jar are coming from `org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache` showed here when running `gradle dependencies`:

```
    |    +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache:5.13.1.202206130422-r
    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.13.1.202206130422-r (*)
    |    |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-osgi:2.7.0
    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30
    |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
    |    |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-sftp:2.7.0
    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:2.7.0
    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-common:2.7.0
```

Am I missing something or is this fairly commonly used package actually has duplicate classes in its dependencies that are breaking usage of it within Android platform out of the box??

Comment: This looks incorrect, Android is more strict and thus complains but it is not a good idea to have duplicate classes in different jars. I'd report a bug at https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/, maybe they need to remove some dependency or exclude the transitive dependency on sshd-common or Apache SSHD needs fixing to not include duplicate stuff in sshd-osgi

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies of JGit should be adjusted to not contain duplicate classes in different jars.

As a workaround you could try to exclude the duplicate transitive dependency on `org.apache.sshd:sshd-common:2.7.0` via the following in `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.sshd', module: 'sshd-common'
}
```